# Splitting a string by whitespaces

Tags: java, string

```
String str = "00 01 02";
String[] strings = str.split(" ");
```

This works as expected. But if I want to add Tab to the list, it stops working, returning the whole string:

```
String[] strings = str.split(" \t");
```

So, as usual, I ask to translate from C# to Java...

Comment: Do you want all white-spaces or just space and tab?

Comment: the split method splits about a regular expression. To split at multiple delimiters you may want to use the StringTokenizer class object. But you will need to use a loop to create your desired string array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] strings = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
str.split("\\s+")
```

It will split on any space and will remove all extra space. To simply include tab, use this:

```
str.split("[ \\t]")
```

Comment: Using `\t` rather than `\\t` should be fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey True, if `\t` is used then java compiler will substitute it with `U+0009` if `\\t` is used then regular expression engine will interpret is as `U+0009`. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762347/understanding-regex-in-java-split-t-vs-split-t-when-do-they-both-wor).

Answer (score 0):

[`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Hello this is Vivek";

String[] sArr = s.split("\\s+");
```

Voila its done..!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First argument of the split method is a regular expression. That means, you have to fill it with the regular expression it suits you the best. If you read here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html you'll see there is a token that suits your requisites the best: \s . It matches whitespaces, tabs and linebreaks (I don't know if you want to cover linebreaks, but chances are you need).

The other question is: should the strings be split by exactly one whitespace/tab? What should happen when you have "00  11 2"? If this is something you want, you'll need to use the +, meaning you want to split by one or more whitespaces/tabs.

Hence, my proposed solution for you:

```
str.split("\\s+")
```