# regex for tab doesnt work | java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm trying to do regex for splitting string when tab is spotted.

I used this :

`String line = scan.nextLine(); String Splitted[] = line.split("\t");`

but it doesn't work so currently I'm using (which is working for me) :

`String line = scan.nextLine(); String Splitted[] = line.split("\\s\\s\\s\\s");`

Do you guys have idea why I can't use the "\t" regex?

Comment: you should use \\t instead of \t additionally you can use \\t+

Comment: Then your string has no tab symbol in it. There is no need using `"\\t"`, a `"\t"` is a valid regex pattern matching a single literal tab. `"\\s\\s\\s\\s"` works most probably because there are 4 consecutive spaces inside the input lines.

Comment: `"abc\tdef".split("\t")` works perfectly well - there probably is no tab (`\t` )  inside your string

Comment: you can use instead of `\t` use `\\s+`

Comment: Your regexp should work, so the problem is probably your input. Tabs should be printed as `9` in this loop. Are they?
    `for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {  System.out.println((int) line.charAt(i));
  }`

Comment: [Read this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3762347/4101906), and i suggest to use `\\s{4,8}`  instead of `\t` or `\\t` or `\u0009` because in some text editors tabs will be replaced with 4,6 or 8 spaces automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `\t` is a valid Regex, but in Java string literals, a backslash has a special meaning, so to get the Regex symbol `\t` you'll have to use `\\t`. But since you are processing user input, you never know what this "tab" really consists of (could be a tab symbol or 4 spaces). So maybe you should just split at `(\\t|\\s{2,})` - beware, this is a Java string literal. Hence the double backslash.

EDIT: In my above answer i suspect you don't want to split at single whitespaces too, is that right? In case you **do want to split at single whitespaces**, you could really just use `\\s+` instead.

Comment: *EDIT: I suspect you don't want to split at single whitespaces too, is that right? In case you do, you could really just use \\s+ instead.* So you think \\s+ wont detect single whitespace ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman you got it wrong. I added bold fonts to make clear what i mean. Anyway, thanks for the hint - my words were a little misleading.

Comment: My answer explains the possible problems of this case and gives a working solution. Why is it being downvoted? @D.Drozd If this solved your problem and could provide help for other users having the same issue, i'd be glad if you marked this answer accepted.