# how to split string with "\\t" in java

Tags: java

i've one text file, and im doing something like this :

```
resultingTokens = currentLine.split("\\t");
```

file data is tab delimited. But when I parse it with above code, it does not give expected output. I realize that tab is actually editor specific. But how does Java (above code) interprets it?

Comment: The tab character is well-defined - it isn't editor-specific. You've said that you're not getting the expected output - but what *are* you getting? And why are you escaping the backslash instead of just using `"\t"`?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635764/string-parsing-in-java-with-delimeter-tab-t-using-split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to split on `\t` (literally backslash followed by lower case T) because you're escaping the backslash. a single backslash with a t will represent a tab.

```
resultingTokens = currentLine.split("\t");
```

is what will give you the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is

```
resultingTokens = currentLine.split("\t");
```

(note the single backslash.)

What you have right now is a two-character string: a single backslash followed by the lowercase letter `t`.

What I am proposing above is a single-character string that consists of the tab character.