# Mysterious Runtime Error in Java

Tags: java, loops, file-io, runtime-error, csv

I'm having issues with a java program i'm writing. It is designed to parse a tab delimited text file, and then store them into an array list. I'm trying to change the format of the tab delimited text file using the java program. My code, however, gets an odd runtime error. Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Parse
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Nelson Liu\\My Documents\\ParsePlanets\\SearchResults.txt"));
            ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
            scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                list.add(scanner.next());
            }
            scanner.close();
            String currenttarget = "Mercury";
            String currentfeaturetype = "Albedo Feature";
            String featuretypebeforecomma = "albedo";
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("jpl-" + currenttarget + "-" + featuretypebeforecomma + ".txt", "UTF-8");
            String classname = "jpl-" + currenttarget + "-" + featuretypebeforecomma;
            int multiplier = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int testingtarget = 0;
            int testingfeature = 0;
            while (multiplier < 15145) {
                testingtarget = (j+2) + (10*multiplier);
                testingfeature = (j + 6) +(10*multiplier);
                if((list.get(testingtarget) == currenttarget) && (list.get(testingfeature) == currentfeaturetype)){
                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("CODE");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-2));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("TARGET");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("DIAMETER");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("LATITUDE-LONGITUDE");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+5));
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+5) + "," + list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+6));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("FEATURE-TYPE");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+4));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("APPROVAL-STATUS");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+5));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("APPROVAL-DATE");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+6));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                    writer.print(classname);
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)-1));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("ORIGIN");
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print(list.get((j+2) + (10*multiplier)+7));
                    writer.print("\t");
                    writer.print("\n");

                }

                multiplier = multiplier +1 ;

            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

I've uncommented lines 1 by 1, and the program works fine, unless the line
multiplier = multiplier +1 ;
is present

odder still, I've tried to use the debugger in my IDE, only to have the main class show up blank.

Stack Trace (copied from comment):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 432, Size: 427 at 
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604) at 
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382) at Parse.main(Parse.java:28) at    
__SHELL4.run(__SHELL4.java:6) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at 
bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)
```

Thanks in advance for all the help, I'm really stuck.

Comment: Show us the error you're getting

Comment: thats what stumps me. there's no error being displayed; the program just terminates. I used the catch block to try to debug, and the program would only output "error" when the multiplier = multiplier+1 line was uncommmented for some reason

edit: could it just be a logical error?

Comment: Most likely you're going out of bounds on `list.get()`, trying to access an index that isn't there.

Comment: well...yea.  that's because you told it to.  do `e.printStackTrace();` instead of `System.out.println("error");` and put the results at the bottom of your question.

Comment: have you tried e.printStackTrace() instead of just printing error so you can see what the error is?

Comment: Also, you still have a closing comment on your last writer.print statement.  That will throw a syntax error as well

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 432, Size: 427
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
 at Parse.main(Parse.java:28)
 at __SHELL4.run(__SHELL4.java:6)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)

Comment: so its an index out of bounds error, but i dont see how line 28 (declaration of the if statement) is wrong. Would you guys care to shed some light?

Comment: Don`t compare Strings with == sign, use equal() in your if-clause. It will give you always false;

Comment: @russelluhl, its just a remnant of debugging, i removed it. thanks.

Comment: 1. What is the purpose of j?
2. Have you tried moving the try/catch so that the try surrounds only the `if((list.get` block? That way, you could print the values of `multiplier`, `testingtarget`, and `testingfeature` in the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `useDelimiter("\\t")`.  See discussion at [String parsing in Java with delimeter tab "\t" using split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635764/string-parsing-in-java-with-delimeter-tab-t-using-split) .

Sample code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "Some\ttab delimited\tstring\twhere\tsome words\tare\tseparated\tby spaces.";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\t");
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Some
tab delimited
string
where
some words
are
separated
by spaces.
```

Comment: nope, it still gives the same error. what could cause the scanner to end prematurely before it finishes the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

Don`t compare Strings with == sign, use equal() in your if-clause. 
In your case there is no printing because the condition in if-clause returns you false because the string you returned from scanner and the string you assigned to "currenttarget" will be compared by reference which are different.

Wrong:

```
if((list.get(testingtarget) == currenttarget) && (list.get(testingfeature) == currentfeaturetype))
```

Correct:

```
if((list.get(testingtarget).equals(currenttarget)) && (list.get(testingfeature).equals(currentfeaturetype)))
```

Comment: ok, do you use eclipse? Do you use debugger? go through the loop once with the debugger to see the values of variables.

Comment: multiplier is used as an index for the list. It is probable that the index is out of bounds for the list at some point.

Comment: i'm downloading eclipse atm, but whats interesting is that it says the size of the array is 427, when in reality it should be around 151450

Comment: While it's a given the equals() should be used rather than ==, the error will be thrown regardless because testingTarget > list.size() -1.

Comment: Yes, for some reason its reading less than it should, im looking more into it

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need flush and close your printwriter after end print, try with writer.flush(); and writer.close(); before  multiplier = multiplier +1 ; and don't use == to compare String use equals

Comment: change System.out.println("error"); with System.out.println(e.getMessage); and paste the result

Comment: it is above, but i've recopied it

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 432, Size: 427 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382) at Parse.main(Parse.java:28) at __SHELL4.run(__SHELL4.java:6) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725) –